# Basicity order of 2nd group oxides

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

It's a general trend that basicity of oxides decreases down the group.

But recently I came across a statement "the basicity of second group oxide decreases down the group and decrease in basic nature of oxide from Be to Ba is due to decrease in polarizing power with increase in ionic size"

I'm not able to understand the relationship between ionic nature and basicity.

Also I feel that more the ionic nature, more the basicity, (as oxygen easily dissociates )

This is question is related to  [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/73890/why-basicity-of-oxides-increases-down-a-group) , but generalised explaination is given, I'm looking for specific explaination to this this particular case

Comment: I have never heard until now that BeO is more basic than BaO...  :-) BeO is in fact amphoteric oxide, while CaO,SrO,BaO are strongly basic.

Comment: So the statement is wrong ?

Comment: Search for chemical properties of elements of the group 2 as broader context.

Comment: @poutnik Wikipedia also identifies magnesium as forming a strongly basic oxide.

Comment: @Oscar Lanzi  I do not object. But it is strongly basic wrt BeO, not wrt CaO-BaO.

Comment: Ah the dangers of classifying things in a bipolar manner when the properties are really a continuum.  See [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/131942/17175) on magnesia, or even lime, being an "alkali" or not.